# ServiceStack using @helper functions to share functionality between views

Tags: razor, servicestack, helper

I have attempted to use the @helper syntax to create helper functions that can be shared between my views.

Mostly I have followed this tutorial http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx but to no avail.

I end up with namespace not found messages when attempting to invoke my helper method.

Is this functionality fully supported in ServiceStack?